# Unable to compile leveldb with snappy support

Tags: c++, cmake, leveldb, snappy

I'm trying to build https://github.com/google/leveldb with support for https://github.com/google/snappy compression on mac os x high sierra for later usage in XCode project, I'm walking through standard compilation procedure described in Readme for both projects. This includes building project via `cmake` for both projects. In case of `snappy` project the procedure is smooth everything builds and installs flawlessly. However in case of `leveldb`, I can't make `cmake` find `snappy` library that I previously installed through `make install`. I don't understand how to debug `cmake` and find the place it looks for libraries.

Any help is appreciated.

Here are results of both builds:
[image]
[image]

---

**EDIT**

Here is an output, it seems that /usr/local/lib is in the list

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Another edit**

I've tried running `cc -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=snappy_compress -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -o check_snappy_exist CheckFunctionExists.c -lsnappy` as per solution provided by `sel-fish`. But if failed with the following output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock, std::__1::allocator<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock> >::__push_back_slow_path<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const>(snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      void std::__1::vector<char*, std::__1::allocator<char*> >::__push_back_slow_path<char* const>(char* const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
  "std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock, std::__1::allocator<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock> >::__push_back_slow_path<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const>(snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      void std::__1::vector<char*, std::__1::allocator<char*> >::__push_back_slow_path<char* const>(char* const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
  "std::length_error::~length_error()", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock, std::__1::allocator<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock> >::__push_back_slow_path<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const>(snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      void std::__1::vector<char*, std::__1::allocator<char*> >::__push_back_slow_path<char* const>(char* const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      snappy::Uncompress(char const*, unsigned long, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      snappy::Compress(char const*, unsigned long, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
  "typeinfo for std::length_error", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock, std::__1::allocator<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock> >::__push_back_slow_path<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const>(snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      void std::__1::vector<char*, std::__1::allocator<char*> >::__push_back_slow_path<char* const>(char* const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for snappy::Sink in libsnappy.a(snappy-sinksource.cc.o)
      typeinfo for snappy::Source in libsnappy.a(snappy-sinksource.cc.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for snappy::ByteArraySource in libsnappy.a(snappy-sinksource.cc.o)
      typeinfo for snappy::UncheckedByteArraySink in libsnappy.a(snappy-sinksource.cc.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for std::length_error", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock, std::__1::allocator<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock> >::__push_back_slow_path<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const>(snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      void std::__1::vector<char*, std::__1::allocator<char*> >::__push_back_slow_path<char* const>(char* const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "operator delete[](void*)", referenced from:
      snappy::Compress(snappy::Source*, snappy::Sink*) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Deleter(void*, char const*, unsigned long) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      snappy::UncompressAsMuchAsPossible(snappy::Source*, snappy::Sink*) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      snappy::Uncompress(snappy::Source*, snappy::Sink*) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      void std::__1::vector<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock, std::__1::allocator<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock> >::__push_back_slow_path<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const>(snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      void std::__1::vector<char*, std::__1::allocator<char*> >::__push_back_slow_path<char* const>(char* const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      snappy::ByteArraySource::~ByteArraySource() in libsnappy.a(snappy-sinksource.cc.o)
      snappy::UncheckedByteArraySink::~UncheckedByteArraySink() in libsnappy.a(snappy-sinksource.cc.o)
  "operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
      snappy::internal::WorkingMemory::GetHashTable(unsigned long, int*) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      snappy::Compress(snappy::Source*, snappy::Sink*) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      snappy::SnappyScatteredWriter<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator>::SlowAppend(char const*, unsigned long) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock, std::__1::allocator<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock> >::__push_back_slow_path<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const>(snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      void std::__1::vector<char*, std::__1::allocator<char*> >::__push_back_slow_path<char* const>(char* const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
  "___cxa_allocate_exception", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock, std::__1::allocator<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock> >::__push_back_slow_path<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const>(snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      void std::__1::vector<char*, std::__1::allocator<char*> >::__push_back_slow_path<char* const>(char* const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
  "___cxa_free_exception", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock, std::__1::allocator<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock> >::__push_back_slow_path<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const>(snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      void std::__1::vector<char*, std::__1::allocator<char*> >::__push_back_slow_path<char* const>(char* const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
  "___cxa_pure_virtual", referenced from:
      vtable for snappy::Sink in libsnappy.a(snappy-sinksource.cc.o)
      vtable for snappy::Source in libsnappy.a(snappy-sinksource.cc.o)
  "___cxa_throw", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock, std::__1::allocator<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock> >::__push_back_slow_path<snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const>(snappy::SnappySinkAllocator::Datablock const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      void std::__1::vector<char*, std::__1::allocator<char*> >::__push_back_slow_path<char* const>(char* const&) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      snappy::GetUncompressedLength(snappy::Source*, unsigned int*) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      snappy::Compress(snappy::Source*, snappy::Sink*) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      snappy::RawUncompressToIOVec(char const*, unsigned long, iovec const*, unsigned long) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      snappy::RawUncompressToIOVec(snappy::Source*, iovec const*, unsigned long) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      snappy::RawUncompress(char const*, unsigned long, char*) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      snappy::RawUncompress(snappy::Source*, char*) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      snappy::Uncompress(char const*, unsigned long, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*) in libsnappy.a(snappy.cc.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that your linker cannot find `/usr/local/lib/libsnappy.a`.

**Try to run `clang -Xlinker -v`**, make sure that `/usr/local/lib` exists in the `Library search paths`:

```
clang -Xlinker -v

@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-278.4
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em (tvOS)
Library search paths:
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
```

Usually, it will exist. Then try `sudo update_dyld_shared_cache`.

Talking about debug `cmake`, you can use flags like `--debug-output`:

```
cmake --debug-output --trace --debug-trycompile ..
```

**UPDATE**:

```
check_library_exists(snappy snappy_compress "" HAVE_SNAPPY)
```

actually do actions as below, it will try to link `snappy` and find if the function exists:

```
cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=snappy_compress -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -o check_snappy_exist CheckFunctionExists.c -lsnappy
```

The source of `CheckFunctionExists.c` you can find [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c).
I think this will simplify the problem.

Comment: libsnappy.a is present in the directory, I've updated my question to reflect that. I've tried running `sudo update_dyld_shared_cache ` but no luck, I'm still unable to compile it together with snappy compression. I've tried running `cmake --debug-output --trace --debug-trycompile ..` but the output is not informative, I've attached the screenshot of it into the question.

Comment: @Lu4 can you check the command i updated? this is what check_library_exists actually does

Comment: @Lu4 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/v8-users/R5bxF5guKpE/ruM-Avuv-AsJ this link seems the same issue as yours, or can you install snappy by `brew install snappy`, seems that your `libsnappy.a` is not proper.

Comment: Thank you sel-fish! I was able to install leveldb from brew and use it in xcode which is perfectly fine for me. Thank you for your time and guidance!

Comment: You're welcome, seems that you solved it by yourself :)

Comment: I've completely lost it that you can install `leveldb` lib from `brew`. Thank you for guidance! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've end-up installing `leveldb` with `brew`. What was also important is to add path in XCode to `User Header Search Paths`, screens below:

[image]
[image]